In the context of imperative languages, I am looking for a metric to describe how "functional", in the sense of "non-imperative", a software module is
I am using TypeScript with classes, interfaces and polymorphism.
A large portion of my project is basically a functional TypeScript-based DSL (domain specific language) that can be used to configure large parts of the the system. This means that if you open a random file in the codebase, the chance that you see assignments, increments, mutations in general is fairly low. In many ways, I could manually classify each file in the category "functional DSL" F or "regular imperative code" I, and compute the functional-ness as F / (F + I). This would be good enough to compare different apps that use the same DSL.
Can you think of general metric that I can apply to pre-existing code-bases, that don't use the DSL? Something that not only reflects the side-effects, but also takes into account how "spread" they are, and how much a mutation in a class can affect another class. Something like a cyclomatic complexity measure, but for side-effect complexity.

It sounds like you are equating 'functional' with 'pure' i.e. functions with no side effects or state mutation.  Is that correct?

I can think of a general metric - but not of one which you can apply to pre-existing code-bases or future code bases to draw any sensible conclusion from it. So it sounds more like an XY problem - tell us what you expect to achieve from such a metric, maybe answerers can show you a better way.

I was just about the ask the same thing @DocBrown asked when I saw his comment pop up. How will this metric help you or your team? The closest I can derive from your question is "... how much a mutation in a class can affect another class" -- are you looking for a metric that allows you to assess how risky it is to make changes to that code?

@JimmyJames Yes, right, probably I should reword it a bit.

@Greg Burghardt I am interested in general in the correlations "software defects VS some metric" and "source comprehension VS some metric". Specifically, the "some metric" that I am seeking to define is about the complexity and spread of mutations in a program state.

@DocBrown For instance, everyone knows that a class that does 2 very different things is usually a code smell. It is my opinion that when 1 of these 2 things is acting as a collection, i.e., having add/remove or register/unregister methods, in addition to some domain specific logic, is even worse. Such class should score exceptionally low according to this metric that I am seeking.

The problem with metrics for things like "spread" is that the degree of locality is often not measurable directly from anything recorded in code, but relies instead on a much richer conceptualisation about the program design which only fully exists in the minds of programmers.
Often, just articulating this conceptualisation in natural language documentation can require a considerable amount of effort, skill, and volume of writing - this creates a need for specialist technical writing skills amongst programmers, imposes up-front work, and imposes a heavy deadweight when change and readaptation are required.
Programming languages themselves are not designed to record this conceptualisation in a formal way that allows mechanical analysis - they are designed primarily for facilitating the most efficient control of the computer by the programmer (i.e. as labour-saving devices for programmers), not to fully distill the matters which concern how the programmer actually exerts that control.
And when you do consider this mental conceptualisation, perceived locality is not always the analogy of physical distance - it can depend more on the perceived strength and obviousness of the connections and cause-and-effect between things.
What may be a strong and obvious connection to one programmer who deeply understands the conceptual domain of a particular application, can be very remote and obscure to another programmer who knows nothing of that domain. The controlling factor in the perceived "distance" here is the extent and relevance of the prior learning and experience of the programmer, rather than a property of the source code.
I think it's fair to say that we know by now that people who ask for these metrics often do so from a place of extreme ignorance about what programming actually involves. My advice would be to take stock and appreciate just how far the typical development activity is from being amenable to these kinds of metrics.

Nobody asked for this metric, nor is expecting for it to be above or below a certain threshold; I would also like to think that I know what programming actually involves, and that is an art, and it is often not very useful to condense anything to a single number, whether it is a codebase, a process, or a person, etc... But, sometimes, it is: if I had to defend/present/promote/write an article about my work, knowing the numbers can be useful (if such numbers can be computed). It's just how science operates: from experimental physics to clinical psychology, audiences value numeric results.

@damix911: sometimes, an "audience values numeric results".  But much more often,  author's try to impress their audience by throwing in some meaningless numbers, because it shall make their work look "more scientific" (though it isn't). The metrics you are asking for has IMHO the huge potential to be good only for the latter. ... (1/2)

... (2/2) IMHO if you really want to assess your code in terms of "how functional" it is, I suggest to analyze if it follows a functional code - imperative shell approach

@damix911, nobody's saying it wouldn't be useful to have a (one-dinensional) metric for these things. The problem, like I say, is the cost of measurement, together with the number of different dimensions. It's not that we can't measure, it's that you'd end up putting a team of academics on it for years to come up with the analysis, the programmer would spend months recording the conceptualisation, and what you'd get out of it would be a complicated multi-dimensional measurement and a massive lump of lead on top of a lightweight development project. (1/3)

That would then beget a demand for meta-analysis to try and reduce the many dimensions to one - a good or bad scale. It would also send another metric bad off the charts - maintainability and speed of readaptation. The culture in which one-dinensional measurements have become popular is not only one where simpletons are in charge of business and are destroying all the capabilities of the Western economy, but where the cost of measurement in large-scale manufacturing has become quite small per repeated piece. (2/3)

Software design is not large-scale manufacturing - it is, in fact, the pinnacle of one-off, decentralised, bespoke design. "Remanufacturing" software to an existing design is as simple as copying - and that's already fully amenable to measurement and fully mechanised. The problem is that the measurements have to be analysed and designed to fit the thing being measured, and that itself requires costly expert labour. (3/3)

I am up-voting this not because I agree with its conclusion, but because I am astonished by the eloquence and insight of the author.  Still, a practical solution should exist.

@MikeNakis, "astonishingly eloquent, insightful, and quite wrong" - I should have that as my epitaph! What is sought with metrics is not merely a "practical" solution, but an economical one, and typically one that is amenable to inexpert interpretation. The belief that this should exist rests, like I say, on the false analogy with manufacturing and the application of metrology to the operation of a manufacturing process. (1/3)

Most people have some experience in participating in the operation of a highly-routinised manufacturing process, because it is one of the main demanders for human labour and has been for generations, and wages and barriers to entry are low so it is especially easy for workers (and petite bourgeois) to come into direct contact with jobs like these. They typically see that measurements and measurement activities and measurement instruments abound in this context. (2/3)

The activity of designing a manufacturing process however is not something many people get to see. And especially not participate in, because it is an expert activity. It is this manufacturing design activity that is more similar to software development, not the manual operation of a process which has already been designed. For developers, the physical activity of the computer itself, which follows their design, is fully measurable. But the expert design and supervision that developers themselves perform, is no more measurable than manufacturing design is. (3/3)
